# Accessing the stack from non x4 addresses - is it possible?

Tags: assembly, att

Ok, this might be a stupid question, but I guess I and others might learn in the process:

I am working with 32-bit assembler, and at&t syntax.

Suppose I want to generate a string dinamically, saving it's content to the stack:

```
.data 
str: .long 0
string: .string "value is %s.\n"
.globl main

movb $0,str+3 #terminate the string
movb $67,str+2
movb $67,str+1
pushl $str
movl %esp,%eax
incl %eax
push (%eax)
push $string
call printf
addl $12,%esp
ret
```

It doesn 't work, and I get a segmentation fault. However, if I comment the line

```
# incl %eax
```

and add another byte at the start of str:

```
movb $67,str
```

then it works perfectly, and CCC is displayed.

It seems that I cannot reference to a string starting from addresses that are not multiple of 4. Or am I wrong? I know I can reference variables from any address, but is there a way to do so with the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you did it wrong. You put the address of the string on the stack, and then tried to increment the address of the address, and dereference it. You want to increment the address. Using `incl (%eax)` to increment the address on the stack should work. However the whole thing is overcomplicated, you can simply do `push $str+1`:

```
movb $0,str+3 #terminate the string
movb $67,str+2
movb $67,str+1
pushl $str+1
push $string
call printf
addl $8,%esp
ret
```

You can access stack unaligned, but then you should make sure it makes sense. Since you had a 4 byte address on the stack, if you access that unaligned, you will get 3 bytes of it, and another byte from the following item on the stack, whatever that may be. This is of course unlikely to be a valid address, hence the segfault. The fault was not for accessing the stack unaligned, it was because you dereferenced an invalid pointer.